# Import from CSV and dedupe using Email (match to contact) with PRIMARY email?

Tags: import, location-type

Is there a way to use "Email (match to contact)" field mapping against the *Primary* email address? Or are we forced to use a location type?

Answer (score 2):

In my testing, for the deduping, it actual matches against any email address no matter what the location type is.  The location type you select for email is for new contacts and what location type their email address will be imported into.